# Unit testing angular 4 component ( form`s field validation) with jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have an angular 4 component which has a form(template driven form) with general fields like date, string and numbers. I want to write unit test cases for this component. Basically when user clicks on submit button I have to verify/validate all the fields, nothing more than this. I have googled a lot but unable to find solution for this. Please help...!
Thanks in advance.
Best Regards,
Madhusudan

Answer (score -5):

Take a look at the [oficial angular testing guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing). It explains all you need.